# eclipse find resource not compiled

Tags: eclipse, dialog, find

When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in **eclipse** I get a dialog that allows me to find a resource. However it shows all resources regardless if they are not compiled or compiled. Is there any way to filter so it shows just not compiled resource? Or can I hide compiled resources in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide compiled resources when you:

- open (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) the "Open resource dialog",
- click on the black triangle on the top right,
- then on "**Show derived resources**": it must be **un-selected**.

You will not see any `.class` file.

From: [What is new in eclipse3.3](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only search for Java classes, then I suggest to use Ctrl-Shift-T.

<strike>For others kinds of resources, I am not sure if you can filter the result of this popup...</strike>
See answer from VonC

Comment: If Ctrl-Shift-T suddenly stop working you can clear the Open Type indexes by going to <Workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core and deleting all files there. The indexes will be re-built the next time you use open type.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional note on VonC's solution, this works as long as the classes are contained within a different directory-tree to the source files - for example many projects build the classes files into a target directory which mirrors the directory structure of the src tree.

In most situations, Eclipse will have set the derived flag on this target directory (right click on target and view properties) - although some Eclipse plugins (Maven/SVN) seem to sometimes get this derived flag wrong (not sure which is the culprit).